# how to increase the value by 1 each time without repeating

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui as pg
pg.FAILSAFE = True
from time import sleep

for i in range(100, 130):

    sleep(1)
    pg.tripleClick(x=1057, y=56)
    pg.typewrite("%d" % i)

    sleep(0.1)
    pg.press('enter')

    i = i + 1
    sleep(0.1)


    pg.tripleClick(x=2734, y=56)
    pg.typewrite("%d" % i)

    sleep(0.1)
    pg.press('enter')

    i = i + 1
    sleep(0.1)


    pg.tripleClick(x=4497, y=56)
    pg.typewrite("%d" % i)

    sleep(0.22)
    pg.press('enter')

    sleep(2)

    i = i + 1
```

I just want to be able to increase the value of i by 1 each time without it repeating the same number. Currently it will write 100, 101, 102 loop to start and then writes 101, 102, 103.
I just want it to continue increasing by 1 each time.
Sorry I am noob, about 5 days into using python

Comment: Seems like you're trying to achieve the result of a `while` loop using a `for` loop. If you want to capture the multiple increments of `i` inside the loop, use something like:
`i = 100` and `while i < 130: <...>`

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you need to add a step value to your for loop. Use something like this:

```
for i in range(100, 130, 3):
    # code
    pg.typewrite("%d" % (i-2))
    # code
    pg.typewrite("%d" % (i-1))
    # code
    pg.typewrite("%d" % i)
```

Obviously, replace the print statements with whatever pyautogui is doing for you. You shouldn't update the `i` variable every single time.

Answer (score 0):

Python for-loops are not like other languages' for-loops. In Python, the first iteration of `for i in range(100, 130):` will always have `i=100`, the next will have `i=101`, the next will have `i=102`, etc., even if you otherwise modify `i`.

Since you actually want `i` to go from `100` on the first iteration to `103` at the top of the loop on the second iteration, you probably want to use `for i in range(100, 130, 3):`. Here, the `3` indicates the amount to increase at each loop.

You can think of `range(100, 130)` as basically meaning `[100, 101, 102, 103, ..., 129]`, while `range(100, 130, 3)` basically means `[100, 103, 106, 109, ..., 127]`. (I say "basically" because these aren't technically lists in memory, but can just be thought of that way.) Each step of the loop just advances the index forward in this "list".

Comment: Perfect! thank you, exactly what I needed to know, perfectly explained.